# vueleaflet map not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3

I am experiencing an issue that others have mentioned where when the map is first loaded, not all the tiles appear, and the map doesn't operate correctly.
[image]

I am importing the JS and CSS at the top of my file:

```js
import 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
```

I am also waiting until the parent component is mounted before rendering the child (map):

```js
const isMounted = ref(false)
onMounted(() => {
  isMounted.value = true
})
<MyMap v-if="isMounted" />
```

The map is being loaded within a container that is styled using flexbox. Could that be the issue?

Some have mentioned that this happens when the map doesn't have correct dimensions when it is instantiated. I am checking this with `offsetHeight` and this does seem to be an issue:

```js
onMounted(() => {
  console.log(mapRef.value.$el.offsetHeight)   // logs 0
})
// from l-map @ready="init"
function init() {
  console.log(mapRef.value.$el.offsetHeight)  // also logs 0 
}
```

The only work around I found for this is to use

```js
setTimeout(() => mapRef.value?.leafletObject.invalidateSize(), 250)
```

But this is less than desirable since it makes the screen flash around and there is a delay.
Has anyone found a fix for this that avoids using `invalidateSize()`?
Is the issue with the flexbox styling and is there a solution for that problem?
Thanks

Comment: Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve]. Without one, we have no way of understanding the reason why you're getting this result and therefore we can't tell you how to fix it. Use codesandbox.io if you need a node-like online environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how helpful this will be to others, but the resolution in our situation was to give `height: 100%;` to an ancestor div.